# Mostrar perfil al listar jugadoras

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en una app de jugadoras de hockey. Donde deben crear un equipo de práctica y a la vez estar seleccionadas para ese equipo.

Ahora estoy listando las selecciones con sus respectivas jugadoras y cuando la jugadora ingresa a los equipo de practica que fue seleccionada, tiene que ver su agenda.

El problema es que al listar me muestra la agenda de todas las jugadoras y solo se debe ver el de la jugadora que ingreso al sistema.

Las tablas:

Tabla perfil (perfil de las jugadoras)

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | nombre | posicion  |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | Laura  | Delantera |
| 2  | Anna   | Defensa   |
| 3  | Mica   | Arquera   |
| 4  | Zoe    | Delantera |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

Tabla equipo (equipo de práctica, lo debe crear la capitana del equipo)

```
+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| idequipo | userid | nombre    |  categoria  |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|    1     |   1    | Equipo A  |    7        |
|    2     |   3    | Equipo B  |    11       |
|    3     |   2    | Equipo C  |    18       |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

Tabla Selección (selección de jugadoras y equipo)

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| idselec  | jugadoraid | equipoid |
+----------+------------+----------+
|    1     |     1      |     3    |
|    2     |     3      |     3    |
|    3     |     2      |     1    |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

Código

```
<?php

$app = new Main(); // Objeto Main, extiende la conexión de la base de datos

$idjugadora = 1;

$postsql = $app->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM seleccion INNER JOIN perfil ON perfil.id = seleccion.jugadoraid INNER JOIN equipo ON equipo.idequipo = seleccion.equipoid WHERE idequipo = 3");
$lista = $postsql->fetchAll();

foreach($lista as $row):

echo "Jugadora: ".$row['nombre'].". Posición: ".$row['posicion'].". Categoría: ".$row['categoria'];
if($row['id'] == $idjugadora){
   echo "Esta es tu agenda ".$row['nombre']."<a href="#">ver</a>";
}

php endforeach;
?>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Te faltó indicar cuál es tu pregunta o problema con este código y estos datos. :)

Comment: Mil disculpas, di al botón de publicar y no había terminado de realizar la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que te falta especificar que busque solo por id de la jugadora, en el `WHERE` solo buscas por `idequipo`

Comment: Claro porque, selecciona un equipo y dentro del equipo están las jugadoras y la jugadora que ingresa a ver a sus compañeras debería ver su agenda

Comment: A ver si entiendo. Listas equipos y en cada equipo hay jugadoras y tu quieres que la jugadora que ingresa a su cuenta vea su agenda, solamente la de ella y con tu consulta se muestran las demás agendas?

Comment: @AntoniaHerrera claro, es así